# "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Rails app on Ubuntu, Apache, Passenger on DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu

This is my first time trying to deploy a Rails app on Digitalocean. I'm using Apache server and PostgreSQL for my DBM. I already have a domain which I'm trying to use for my app. Whenever I try to access my website with the domain I get:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

These are the logs I'm getting.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.0987 27388/7f60283aa7c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:883 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.0991 27388/7f60283aa7c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:232 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.1069 27388/7f60283aa7c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:637 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 27388
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.1462 27393/7f2a835cc7c0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:431 ]: Starting PassengerAgent logger...
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.1480 27393/7f2a835cc7c0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:312 ]: PassengerAgent logger online, PID 27393
[Wed Jun 03 10:40:27.148890 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17706:tid 140076804220800] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 10:40:27.148934 2015] [core:notice] [pid 17706:tid 140076804220800] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[ 2015-06-03 10:40:27.4303 26722/7f90f511f7c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:868 ]: PassengerAgent server shutdown finished
App 27471 stdout: 
App 27489 stdout:
```

`log/production.log`:

```
I, [2015-06-03T11:16:29.516619 #27489]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 186.155.86.153 at 2015-06-03 11:16:29 -0400
F, [2015-06-03T11:16:29.543227 #27489] FATAL -- :
PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "Metalmind_2"):
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1.rc4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1.rc4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1.rc4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1.rc4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1.rc4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1.rc4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1.rc4) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:85:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

I've been trying a lot of things already but can't find what the problem is. I appreciate if someone can give me a hand!

Comment: show more of your application log..

Comment: tail -100 log/production.log :)

Comment: Already added more logs, thanx for your help!

Comment: `PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "Metalmind_2" ):`..simply says, database authentication failed.

Comment: I am getting an error as `The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while starting your web application. Because you are running this web application in staging or production mode, the details of the error have been omitted from this web page for security reasons` while running redmine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are having PG error, you can make these changes:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
 Change => local all all ident
 To => local all all trust
 if still do not work change to=> local all all md5
 Then restart your postgres server
 sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: thank you so much but it didn't work. I keep getting the same error. :(

Comment: Please have a look at my github page for complete setup of postgres -https://github.com/adnan87/RailsConfigDocs/blob/master/Postgres.md